# Redirect primary domain to parked domain

Tags: seo, web-hosting, domains, redirects, dns

The problem is as follows:
We already have registered domain name (example.com.hr) via a Croatian domain name provider.

During the web hosting registration process, the registrar doesn't offer a field where I can input my own domain name, and basically forces me to register a .com domain name.

Is there a way to redirect from the primary domain to a parked domain, or somehow register with Google and instruct them to absolutely ignore my primary domain to avoid any bad ranking issues?

I guess I can do a redirect with PHP headers since I'll have WordPress installed, but I'm not sure how this affects SEO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redirect using the following

- Forward the domain from the registrar
- Create a CNAME record
- Meta refresh
- 301 redirect

I would not redirect using PHP you can redirect much sooner than before the visitors get to your application on the .com

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can tell Google which is your preferred domain name for a site that's served under multiple domains: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=44231

Comment: I think this is just to chose between with www and without www domain name.